# creating tab switch using javascript

Tags: javascript, tabs

hi guys: i have created a tab switch using js+html+css, as required by a js exercise. the code is shown as following:

```js
var tab1 = document.getElementById('tab1'),
  tab2 = document.getElementById('tab2'),
  tab3 = document.getElementById('tab3'),
  c1 = document.getElementById('c1'),
  c2 = document.getElementById('c2'),
  c3 = document.getElementById('c3');

function changeTab1() {
  tab1.className = 'selected';
  tab2.className = '';
  tab3.className = '';
  c1.className = 'show'
  c2.className = '';
  c3.className = '';
}

function changeTab2() {
  tab1.className = '';
  tab2.className = 'selected';
  tab3.className = '';
  c1.className = '';
  c2.className = 'show';
  c3.className = '';
}

function changeTab3() {
  tab1.className = '';
  tab2.className = '';
  tab3.className = 'selected';
  c1.className = ''
  c2.className = '';
  c3.className = 'show';
}
```

```css
h2 {
  border-top: solid cornflowerblue 1px;
  border-left: solid cornflowerblue 1px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab-content {
  border: solid cornflowerblue 1px;
  width: 152px;
  height: 100px;
}

.tab-content div {
  display: none;
}

.selected {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.tab-content .show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="js/tab.js" type="text/javascript">
<div class="tab-head">
  <h2 id="tab1" onclick="changeTab1()" class="selected">1</h2>
  <h2 id="tab2" onclick="changeTab2()">2</h2>
  <h2 id="tab3" onclick="changeTab3()">3</h2>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="c1" class="show">content1</div>
  <div id="c2">content2</div>
  <div id="c3">content3</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me why the tab switch does not work when i click on h2 with id=tab1, tab2, & tab3 respectively? do i need to cite any external sources? i have written the onclick at each of the headings element, and i am just wondering what is causing all those trouble for me here.

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid reference of `tab.js` in your code. Remove it and try again. Below is a working snippet of the same code.

```js
var tab1 = document.getElementById('tab1'),
  tab2 = document.getElementById('tab2'),
  tab3 = document.getElementById('tab3'),
  c1 = document.getElementById('c1'),
  c2 = document.getElementById('c2'),
  c3 = document.getElementById('c3');

function changeTab1() {
  tab1.className = 'selected';
  tab2.className = '';
  tab3.className = '';
  c1.className = 'show'
  c2.className = '';
  c3.className = '';
}

function changeTab2() {
  tab1.className = '';
  tab2.className = 'selected';
  tab3.className = '';
  c1.className = '';
  c2.className = 'show';
  c3.className = '';
}

function changeTab3() {
  tab1.className = '';
  tab2.className = '';
  tab3.className = 'selected';
  c1.className = ''
  c2.className = '';
  c3.className = 'show';
}
```

```css
h2 {
  border-top: solid cornflowerblue 1px;
  border-left: solid cornflowerblue 1px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab-content {
  border: solid cornflowerblue 1px;
  width: 152px;
  height: 100px;
}

.tab-content div {
  display: none;
}

.selected {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.tab-content .show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-head">
  <h2 id="tab1" onclick="changeTab1()" class="selected">1</h2>
  <h2 id="tab2" onclick="changeTab2()">2</h2>
  <h2 id="tab3" onclick="changeTab3()">3</h2>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="c1" class="show">content1</div>
  <div id="c2">content2</div>
  <div id="c3">content3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i deleted the tab.js part of my code, but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @KeYangZippie -- did you the snippet in my answer? Is it what you want with the tabs to behave?

Comment: i wanted the tabs to be able to switch. i didn't snippet in your answer. i physically removed the js/tabs.js part from the codes.

Comment: hey bro, i tried what u had told me, but it was just not working properly.